# Unable to retrieve ExperienceBundle from developer edition org

Tags: experience-bundle

I've enabled Experience in my Developer Edition org. Created a site using LWR framework.  Enabled "ExperienceBundle Metadata API" option. Site is published/active/etc.

When I attempt to retrieve from IDE, I am unable to pull down the ExperienceBundle. It appears in the metadata subscription, but actual retrieval fails. The "experience" is the same in IntelliJ & VS Code.

The below is returned in VS Code when retrieving package.xml and/or using OrgBrowser to insert.

[image]

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

***update*** *this issue isn't present in my older Developer Edition org's! just on recent DE and scratch org's.*

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you check if the metadata you want is the `DigitalExperienceBundle` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_digitalexperiencebundle.htm)) because it might be the Enhanced LWR site you have created.

I also suggest you review this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm&type=5) that can clarify more details on differences between different sites and Metadata.